# Sub-module cobertura jenkins reports

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, cobertura

We have project with following layout

1. parent

   - app
   - core
   - instrumentation

There is cobertura plugin in core module. I'm able to generate reports from command line no problem at all (XML and HTML) I'm even able to see them in workspace on Jenkins. However I'm not able to link these reports with Jenkins Cobertura plugin.
The default as per Jenkins documentation is

```
**/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
```

This doesn't work due to reports generated in sub-module. I tried following

```
core/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
/core/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
**/core/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
```

Comment: Where are the reports located relative to ${WORKSPACE}?

Comment: Going to workspace option I will reach reports through  core/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the problem is that I used cobertura plugin as

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <formats>
              <format>xml</format>
              <format>html</format>
            </formats>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

Instead it should be as

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <formats>
            <format>xml</format>
            <format>html</format>
          </formats>
          <check/>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>cobertura</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin> 
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins> 
  </reporting>
```

After this I point Jenkins Cobertura plugin to *core/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml*

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines to your application Goals:(configure section of the application in jenkins)

```
cobertura:cobertura -Dcobertura.report.format=xml
```

Cobertura xml report pattern:
*/target/site/cobertura/.xml

pom.xml changes:

```
<reporting>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <formats>
                <format>html</format>
                <format>xml</format>
            </formats>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```